# Magento - /api?wsdl not working (none of the api urls are working)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have done the basic setup for Magento on an Ubuntu 12.04. Everything seems to work fine, uploading products, listing products etc. But for some reason the "/api" is not working.

I have changed the admin roles and attributes, even allowed total access to guest and customer accounts but still for some reason I am not able to perform a basic request from the api.

One strange thing that happens though is even though `"http://localhost/magento/api/?wsdl"` doesn't work, `"http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/?wsdl"` seems to return some XML.

What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that "some xml" is the API!!

Comment: but this "http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/products?limit=2" gives a page not found error

Answer (score 3):

The URLs containing `index.php` are the correct API urls.

The Magento API is not a simple, "browsable in a browser" RESTful api.  The original "Magento API" is an API accessible via the SOAP or XML-RPC protocols. You can read about http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-SupportedTypes">it here.  Your client language of choice should have tools for making API calls with these protocols.

Newer versions of Magento also have a ["REST" api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html).  This API **is** accessible via logically named URLs.  However, you need to [authenticate with oAuth](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-PreparingRESTAPIfortheThirdPartyApplication), which means you can't just browse to URLs.

Comment: I want to use the REST api. I was testing the web services but it shows  the error "page not found"

Comment: @binay37 There's a full list of instructions on setting up the REST API at the link above.  Based on your question, you're not using the correct `https://magentohost/api/rest/` or `https://magentohost/api/rest/` URL

Answer (score 2):

Just move `api.php` to `_api.php` or remove it altogether, and the request path `/api/...` is instantly fixed - no 404 or "Invalid webservice adapter specified" error.

This seems to have something to do with Apache (in our case, at least) interpreting requests to `/api` as pertaining to `api.php` in the web root and I've no idea how to change this behaviour even after researching (googling) the problem repeatedly over the last year.

Bit late with this answer, I know, but I hope the primitive fix helps someone else with the same issue, or better yet - I hope someone cleverer than I am comes along and explains how to change this behaviour properly!

Answer (score 0):

If the url returns an XML, you're probably trying to test your connection from your own server and your server can't resolve your hostname.

Try to test your API from another server.

Comment: How can I do that on my local machine?

Comment: Change your api url from localhost to "127.0.0.1" and then try to connect.